# Splash screen horizontal positioning inconsistent

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I am creating a site which shows an animated gif as the splash screen. Unfortunately the horizontal sizing when viewed on iPhone is inconsistent.
The animated gif appears way off to the right of the centre of the screen when the site is first loaded. If the site is reloaded, then it seems to work just fine.

Suggestions much appreciated :)

Here is the code:

---

HTML

```
<div id="overlay">
<div id="overlay-content"><img src='videosmall.gif'></div>
</div>
```

---

CSS

```
#overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
}

#overlay-content {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
}
```

---

JavaScript (jQuery)

```
function main() {
  $('#overlay').show();
  $('#overlay-content').show().center();
}


setTimeout(function() {
  $("#overlay").fadeOut();
  $('.i3section').fadeIn(5000);
}, 5000);



$.fn.center = function() {
  this.css("position", "absolute");
  this.css("top", Math.max(0, (
      ($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) +
    $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");

  this.css("left", Math.max(0, (
      ($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) +
    $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
  return this;
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a working code snippet or JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid this problem by using CSS in order to position overlay and its content.
+ The animation will be much smoother

Example:

HTML

```
<div id="overlay">
  <img src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=6e4af45f4d66'>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#overlay {
  /* Display overlay in fullscreen */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;

  /* Center it's content */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  /* Add nice animation */
  transition: visibility 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;

  /* While it's hidden */
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
#overlay.open {
  /* While it's shown */
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
#overlay img {
  /* Styling image */
  display: block;
  width: 128px;
  height: auto;
}
```

JS

```
/* Showing the overlay */
$('#overlay').addClass('open');

setTimeout(function () 
{
  /* Hiding the overlay */
  $('#overlay').removeClass('open');
}, 3000);
```

FIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/JacobDesight/vkga6mhk/